# Haskell Collect Runtime of Function

Tags: haskell

I have a Haskell function which I need to collect runtime for over a series of inputs running 0 to 1,000,000 in steps of 100. Now, I would usually set ghci to :set +s, but I'm not really keen on manually running the script thousands of times.

I was wondering if there was any way I could code a Haskell function to return the runtime of another function.

Thanks
Dario

Comment: The timeit package allows simple timing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the entire [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) package for doing this. As opposed to ghci, it runs the code with optimizations, too.

Start with the `Criterion.Main` module.

Criterion isn't well-suited to collecting data for each of a million data points, but it could be used that way.

I'd certainly trust its results way more than the results of a single timing for each of million data points. But it would take a while to collect a million results.

Comment: What I'd really need is to collect individual runtime for each point. What I did was creating an external ghci file which I then load using :def . readFile :. myfile.ghci. However, I need a way of recording the output to a txt file or similar. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ie - storing all GHCI output in a file